# Could not find package database with package stability stable

Tags: laravel

Hi I was creating a project in laravel and it needed a database. I am using composer to create the database.
Command: "composer create database blog"

I get an error could not find package database with stability stable. Can someone explain why this error occurs?
I have attached an image showing the command prompt. Operating System: Windows 10. I have installed composer. I am using Wamp.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHeGr.png)

Comment: What environment you use? WAMP, XAMPP, Vagrant, something else? Btw you can't create DB with composer.

Comment: Composer is a dependency management tool for PHP. Not sure what are you trying to get but I don't think that you're researching the correct tool. As @Tpojka asked, I would suggest to try some built environment as WAMP, XAMPP or better Homestead.

Comment: I am using WAMP.